# spring boot 2.0 + thymeleaf unix epoch to date

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf, epoch

I'm new to spring boot and thymeleaf. I did try to research for a while but could not get it to work. I'm calling a 3rd party api that returns an object that has a field in unix epoch timestamp. The value is returned as Long.

In thymeleaf I tried below but get a totally different date. The timestamp is for today. But the date displayed is wrong.

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    <!--<version>1.5.13.RELEASE</version> -->
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

epoch value

```
1531879826
```

view

```
<td th:text="${#dates.format(discount?.start, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss')}">date</td>
```

displayed date is wrong. It should be today's date/time.

```
18-01-1970 12:31:19
```

Any help to steer me in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to get it right you have to use longer value for epoch time.
In java you need to multiply it by 1000, since it is using milliseconds.

I assume that:

```
<td th:text="${#dates.format(discount?.start * 1000, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss')}">date</td>
```

will do the job.

Try it.